# Dragging windows in Ubuntu Unity

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.04, ubuntu-unity

I updated Ubuntu to version 11.04 and it uses Unity. I noticed that for most programs, I can't simply drag them around like I used to. I have to hold the alt key in order to drag them around. Is this normal?

Why is it like this? How can dragging windows in Unity be made easier so that I don't have to always press the alt key?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is intended that you can drag your windows when you invoke your <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. I don't have a reasonable answer for why it is like this.

If you are looking to simplify the dragging process, you can drag the windows around without using <kbd>Alt</kbd> key by clicking on the title bar and dragging like you normally do.